# How to add a link in wordpress theme and manage that link's url from content managed post?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, html-lists

I have a hard-coded link in my Wordpress theme but I need for the link to be able to be managed from within a Wordpress post. How can I go about pulling the link url, from a post (or something similar which is content managed) and put that into the link?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) in the post page. You can retrieve it using [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) in your theme. Example, assuming you are in the loop!

```
$custom_link = get_post_meta($post->ID,'custom_link',true)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. Custom fields are here to do this kind of stuffs!

Comment: Hi Keatch. I've read through the documentation and tested a number of options here but not getting the desired results. Here is my get_post_meta() which is in the loop of the page:

<?php $key_1_values = get_post_meta(105, 'buy-now','true'); ?>

I am assuming there for that my custom field should therefor display on my pages as buy-now:products-page/bags/laptop-bag/

Something I am doing is not correct. I am not a php developer so I am following instructions as they come from SO and Wordpress. Thanks